# Convert FileReader.readAsText() result string back into a file object for download?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, download

I have a file upload component where the file is processed using fileReader.readAsText(), then converted to base64 and sent to the server.

The issue is I need to also allow the user to download the file again.  I have decoded it, tried to convert to an ArrayBuffer (among other things) then download but have had no success.  I have researched all around SO and haven't found anything.  This is how I'm trying to download:

```
 downloadFile (type) {
  // the file is already decoded at this point and is the result of
  // fileReader.readAsText()
  var reader = new FileReader()
  var blob = new Blob([this.uploadedFile])
  reader.onload = function () {
    var temp = reader.result
    var a = document.createElement('a')
    a.download = 'test.pdf'
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([temp], {type: 'application/pdf'}))
    a.dataset.downloadurl = [a.download, a.href].join(':')
    a.click()
  }
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob)
}
```

Once it comes out it downloads just a blank PDF (I also have to support .rtf, .odf, .doc, .docx.)  Maybe I just have the wrong data format?

Comment: If you open the file directly from the backend, does it open correctly? This quickly boils down to either the upload or download part having errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution.  Instead of doing fileReader.readAsText() I changed to fileReader.readAsDataURL() and then the download looks like this now

```
downloadFile() {
  var a = document.createElement('a')
  a.download = fileName
  a.href = fileData
  a.dataset.downloadurl = [a.download, a.href].join(':')
  a.click()
}
```

The issue was indeed the wrong data format in the beginning!